# Problema en suma sobrecargada con punteros array

Tags: c++, array, punteros, sobrecarga, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Tengo un operador + sobrecargado que devuelve un objeto de tipo IntArr, la suma de arrays se realiza bien dentro de la función pero cuando hago A=B+C los primeros dos elementos no se copian, dejando unos numeros cualquiera, por qué pasa esto?

Gracias

Función sobrecargada:

```
 IntArr IntArr::operator+(IntArr A){
    IntArr aux=*this;
    if(aux.used+A.used>aux.size){
        aux.espaciar(A.used);    //espaciar aumenta el tamaño del array
    }
    for (int i=0;i<A.used;i++){
        aux.p[aux.used+i]=A.p[i];
    }
    aux.used+=A.used;
    return aux;
}
```

Constructor Copia:

```
IntArr::IntArr(const IntArr &arr){
    size=arr.size;
    used=arr.used;
    p=new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<used;i++){
        p[i]=arr.p[i];
    }
}
```

Main:

```
cout<<"\n> Array B\n"<<B;  --> B=[99,1,2,3,4,5,6]
cout<<"\n> Array C\n"<<C;  --> C=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
A=B+C;
cout<<"\n> Array A=B+C\n"<<A; -->da [5298323,6404288,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Funcion Espaciar:

```
void IntArr::espaciar(int cant){
    if (cant>5){
        size+=cant;
    }
    else{
        size+=5+cant;
    }

    int *aux=new int[size];
    for (int i=0;i<used;i++){
        aux[i]=p[i];
    }
    delete []p;
    p=aux;
}
```

Lo solucione sobrecargando al operador `=`, haciendolo que haga la copia del otro objeto. Por si a alguien le sirve de ayuda

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la definición de la función `espaciar`?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus ya pude solucionar el problema, solo tuve que sobrecargar el operador `=` para hacerlo que copie otro objeto, de todas formas agregué la función `espaciar`. Gracias Paula

Comment: Si esta pregunta ya no tiene sentido te sugiero que la elimines.

Comment: Por qué borrarla? Puede que a alguien le sea de ayuda.